# Why is my JS Ternary ignoring the conditional argument where the affirmative should execute a map.set(k,v) function?

Tags: javascript, mapping, ternary

The goal is to map `data-` attributes from one element to another, but while ignoring certain attributes such as `class`, `id`, etc.

Here is a block:

```js
    let ignoreList = ['class', 'id', 'name', 'value', 'type', 'src'];
    $(".some-class").on("click",function(event) {
        let attrMap = new Map();
        let attrs = event.target.attributes;
        $.each(attrs, function(e){
            console.log(`"${this.name}" is in ignoreList: ` + (ignoreList.indexOf(this.name) == 0).toString());
            ignoreList.indexOf(this.name) == 0 ? attrMap.set(this.name, this.value) : null;
        });
        console.log(attrs);
        console.log(attrMap);
    });
```

What I would have expected in the `console` would be:

```
"class" is in ignoreList: true
"data-one" is in ignoreList: false
"data-two" is in ignoreList: false
"data-three" is in ignoreList: false
"data-four" is in ignoreList: false
"data-five" is in ignoreList: false
"data-six" is in ignoreList: false

NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: data-one, 2: data-two, 3: data-three, 4: data-four, 5: data-five, 6: data-six, class: class, data-one: data-one, data-two: data-two, data-three: data-three, data-four: data-four, …}

Map(6) {'data-one' => 'Lorem ipsum', 'data-two' => 'dolor sit amet', 'data-three' => 'purto ludus', 'data-four' => 'indoctum sit', …}
```

What I am getting in the `console`:
*(repeated values ignored for brevity)*

```
Map(1) {'class' => 'some-class'}
```

I have tried various logics in the conditional, such as `< 0`, `== -1`, `!= 0`

Comment: why not iterate directly over `dataset`?

Comment: That's a confusing way to use ternary operator, use a simple `if` instead. Don't minify your development code.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I thought about it, but I wasn't sure how to get around the keys being  different ergo: "data-this-data" in the element -> "thisData" in the dataset

Comment: `.indexOf(this.name) == 0` is only true when `this.name` is `class`. Use `includes` or a `Set` instead.

Comment: oh my gosh - @gog, either too much coffee or not enough.  You hit the nail on the head, I was using the reverse logic.  `.indexOf(this.name) == -1` solves this. <eggOnFace> me </eggOnFace>

Comment: @brian-welch, better take `includes` instad of `indexOf` by not using index values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `console.log(ignoreList.indexOf(this.name))` you'll get always `-1` in your case, but you're forcefully trying to match the result of [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with an *index* of `== 0`.

Instead, to check if an array *includes* a value, use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and save the Boolean result into a variable say `isIgnored`. Then you could use `if (!isIgnored) /*set*/` or simply: `!isIgnored && /*set*/`, **no ternary needed**:

```js
const ignoreList = ['class', 'id', 'name', 'value', 'type', 'src'];

const mapAttrs = (event) => {

  const attrMap = new Map();
  const attrs = event.currentTarget.attributes;

  [...attrs].forEach((attr) => {
    const isIgnored = ignoreList.includes(attr.name);
    console.log(`"${attr.name}" is in ignoreList: ${isIgnored}`);
    !isIgnored && attrMap.set(attr.name, attr.value);
  });
  
  console.log(attrs);
  console.log(attrMap);
};


document.querySelectorAll(".some-class").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", mapAttrs);
});
```

```html
<div
    class="some-class"
    data-one="one"
    data-two="two"
    data-three="three"
    data-four="four"
    data-five="five"
    data-six="six"
>Open Dev tools Console (F12) and - Click me</div>
```